# How to read list of config from docker-compose.yml to application.yml?

Tags: java, docker, docker-compose

I have a Java application that read properties from the `application.yml` file. The Java application reads data from multiple sources, does some processing, and dumps output to the Postgres table. The input sources are a list of variable number of sources. My application.yml is below:

```
inputSources:
  - type: POSTGRES
    # postgres configs
  - type: MYSQL
    # mysql configs
   ....
```

I want to deploy my application as a `docker` container. I am using the `docker-compose.yml` file to define all the properties. Is there a way in which I can define a variable number of sources in the docker-compose.yml file and read it directly into the `application.yml` file instead of reading the property one by one?

Comment: Is your applicatipn Spring-boot based?

Comment: @gdomo No It is an not spring-boot project